# Sort a column based on the sorting of a column from another pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
 df1:
 col1    col2 
  P        1
  Q        3
  M        2
```

I have another dataframe:

```
df2:
col1      col2
 Q         1
 M         3
 P         9
```

I want to sort the col1 of df2 based on the order of col1 of df1. So the final dataframe will look like:

```
 df3:
 col1     col2
  P         1
  Q         3
  M         9
```

How to do it using pandas or any other effective method ?

Comment: what is the condition for sorting????

Comment: Are values in `col1` unique in both `DataFrame`s ?

Comment: @jezrael yes unique

Answer (score 3):

You could set `col1` as index in `df2` using [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and index the dataframe using `df1.col11` with [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df2.set_index('col1').loc[df1.col1].reset_index()

   col1  col2
0    P     9
1    Q     1
2    M     3
```

Or as @jpp suggests you can also use [`.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) instead of `.loc`:

```
df2.set_index('col1').reindex(df1.col1).reset_index()
```

Comment: You can also use `reindex(df1.col1)` instead of `loc`.